# Should a TCP client be able to pause the server, when the TCP server reads a non-blocking socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

### Overview

I have a simple question with code below.  Hopefully I didn't make a mistake in the code.

I'm a network engineer, and I need to test certain linux behavior of our business application keepalives during network outages (I'm going to insert some iptables stuff later to jack with the connection - first I want to make sure I got the client & server right).

As part of a network failure test I'm conducting, I wrote a non-blocking Python TCP client and server that are supposed to blindly send messages to each other in a loop.  To understand what's happening I am using loop counters.

The server's loop should be relatively straightforward.  I loop through every fd that `select` says is ready.  I never even import `sleep` anywhere in my server's code.  From this perspective, I don't expect the server's code to pause while it loops over the client's socket <strike>, but for some reason the server code pauses intermittently</strike> (more detail, below).

I initially didn't put a sleep in the client's loop.  Without a sleep on the client side, the server and client seem to be as efficient as I want.  However, when I put a `time.sleep(1)` statement *after the client does an `fd.send()` to the server*, the TCP server code <strike>intermittently</strike> pauses while the client is sleeping.

**My questions:**

- <strike>Should I be able to write a single-threaded Python TCP server that doesn't pause when the client hits `time.sleep()` in the client's `fd.send()` loop?  If so, what am I doing wrong?</strike> <- ANSWERED
- If I wrote this test code correctly and the server *shouldn't pause*, why is the TCP server <strike>intermittently</strike> pausing while it polls the client's connection for data?

### Reproducing the scenario

I'm running this on two RHEL6 linux machines. To reproduce the issue...

- Open two different terminals.
- Save the client and server scripts in different files
- Change the shebang path to your local python (I'm using Python 2.7.15)
- Change the `SERVER_HOSTNAME` and `SERVER_DOMAIN` in the client's code to be the hostname and domain of the server you're running this on
- Start the server first, then start the client.

After the client connects, you'll see messages as shown in EXHIBIT 1 scrolling quickly in the server's terminal.  <strike>After a few seconds</strike> The scrolling pauses <strike>intermittently</strike> when the client hits `time.sleep()`.  I don't expect to see those pauses, but maybe I've misunderstood something.

**EXHIBIT 1**

```
---
LOOP_COUNT 0
---
LOOP_COUNT 1
---
LOOP_COUNT 2
---
LOOP_COUNT 3
CLIENTMSG: 'client->server 0'
---
LOOP_COUNT 4
---
LOOP_COUNT 5
---
LOOP_COUNT 6
---
LOOP_COUNT 7
---
LOOP_COUNT 8
---
LOOP_COUNT 9
---
LOOP_COUNT 10
---
LOOP_COUNT 11
---
```

### Summary resolution

> If I wrote this test code correctly and the server shouldn't pause, why is the TCP server intermittently pausing while it polls the client's connection for data?

Answering my own question. My blocking problem was caused by calling select() with a non-zero timeout.

When I changed select() to use a zero-second timeout, I got expected results.

### Final non-blocking code (incorporating suggestions in answers):

- See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77533502/667301)

### Original Question Code:

**tcp_server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, SOL_SOCKET
#from socket import MSG_OOB  <--- for send()
from socket import socket
import socket as socket_module
import select
import fcntl
import os

host = ''
port = 9997

serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SOCK_STREAM, 1)
serv_sock.bind((host, port))
serv_sock.listen(5)

fcntl.fcntl(serv_sock, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)  # Make the socket non-blocking

sock_list = [serv_sock]

from_client_str = '__DEFAULT__'

to_client_idx = 0
loop_count = 0
while True:
    recv_ready_list, send_ready_list, exception_ready = select.select(sock_list, sock_list,
        [], 5)

    print "---"
    print "LOOP_COUNT",  loop_count

    ## Read all sockets which are input-ready... might be client or server...
    for sock_fd in recv_ready_list:

        # accept() if we're reading on the server socket...
        if sock_fd is serv_sock:
            clientsock, clientaddr = sock_fd.accept()
            sock_list.append(clientsock)

        # read input from the client socket...
        else:
            try:
                from_client_str = sock_fd.recv(4096)
                if from_client_str=='':
                    # Client closed the socket...
                    print "CLIENT CLOSED SOCKET"
                    sock_list.remove(sock_fd)
            except socket_module.error, e:
                print "WARNING RECV FAIL"


            print "from_client_str: '{0}'".format(from_client_str)

    for sock_fd in send_ready_list:
        if sock_fd is not serv_sock:
            try:
                to_client_str = "server->client: {0}\n".format(to_client_idx)
                sock_fd.send(to_client_str)
                to_client_idx += 1
            except socket_module.error, e:
                print "TO CLIENT SEND ERROR", e

    loop_count += 1
```

**tcp_client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
    
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from socket import gethostname, socket
import socket as socket_module
import select
import fcntl
import errno
import time
import sys
import os

## NOTE: Using this script to simulate a scheduler
SERVER_HOSTNAME = 'myHostname'
SERVER_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.local'
PORT = 9997

def handle_socket_error_continue(e):
    ## non-blocking socket info from:
    ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745561/667301
    print "HANDLE_SOCKET_ERROR_CONTINUE"
    err = e.args[0]
    if (err==errno.EAGAIN) or (err==errno.EWOULDBLOCK):
        print 'CLIENT DEBUG: No data input from server'
        return True
    else:
        print 'FROM SERVER RECV ERROR: {0}'.format(e)
        sys.exit(1)

c2s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # Client to server socket...
c2s.connect(('.'.join((SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_DOMAIN,)), PORT))
# Set socket non-blocking...
fcntl.fcntl(c2s, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

to_srv_idx = 0
while True:
    socket_list = [c2s]

    # Get the list sockets which can: take input, output, etc...
    recv_ready_list, send_ready_list, exception_ready = select.select(
        socket_list, socket_list, [])

    for sock_fd in recv_ready_list:
        assert sock_fd is c2s, "Strange socket failure here"

        #incoming message from remote server
        try:
            from_srv_str = sock_fd.recv(4096)
        except socket_module.error, e:
            ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745561/667301
            err_continue = handle_socket_error_continue(e)
            if err_continue is True:
                continue
        else:
            if len(from_srv_str)==0:
                print "SERVER CLOSED NORMALLY"
                sys.exit(0)

        ## NOTE: if we get this far, we successfully received from_srv_str.
        ##    Anything caught above, is some kind of fail...
        print "from_srv_str: {0}".format(from_srv_str)

    for sock_fd in send_ready_list:
        #incoming message from remote server
        if sock_fd is c2s:
            #to_srv_str = raw_input('Send to server: ')
            try:
                to_srv_str = 'client->server {0}'.format(to_srv_idx)
                sock_fd.send(to_srv_str)

                               ##
                time.sleep(1)  ## Client blocks the server here... Why????
                               ##

                to_srv_idx += 1
            except socket_module.error, e:
                print "TO SERVER SEND ERROR", e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I put a time.sleep(1) statement after the client does an
>   fd.send() to the server, the TCP server code intermittently pauses
>   while the client is sleeping.

AFAICT from running the provided code (nice self-contained example, btw), the server is behaving as intended.

In particular, the semantics of the `select()` call are that `select()` shouldn't return until there is something for the thread to do.  Having the thread block inside `select()` is a *good thing* when there is nothing that the thread can do right now anyway, since it prevents the thread from spinning the CPU for no reason.

So in this case, your server program has told `select()` that it wants `select()` to return only when at least one of the following conditions is true:

1. `serv_sock` is ready-for-read (which is to say, a new client wants to connect to the server now)
2. `serv_sock` is ready-for-write (I don't believe this ever actually happens on a listening-socket, so this criterion can probably be ignored)
3. `clientsock` is ready-for-read (that is, the client has sent some bytes to the server and they are waiting in `clientsock`'s buffer for the server thread to `recv()` them)
4. `clientsock` is ready-for-write (that is, `clientsock` has some room in its outgoing-data-buffer that the server could `send()` data into if it wants to send some data back to the client)
5. Five seconds have passed since the call to `select()` started blocking.

I see (via print-debugging) that when your server program blocks, it is blocking inside `select()`, which indicates that none of the 5 conditions above are being met during the blocking-period.

Why is that?  Well, let's go down the list.

1. Not met because no other clients are trying to connect
2. Not met because this never happens
3. Not met because the server has read all of the data that the connected client has sent (and since the connected client is itself sleeping, it's not sending any more data)
4. Not met because the server has filled up the outgoing-data buffer of its `clientsock` (because the client program is sleeping, it's only reading the data coming from the server intermittently, and the TCP layer guarantees lossless/in-order transmission, so once `clientsock`'s outgoing-data-buffer is full, `clientsock` won't select-as-ready-for-write unless/until the client reads at least some data from its end of the conenction)
5. Not met because 5 seconds haven't elapsed yet since `select()` started blocking.

So is this behavior actually a problem for the server?  In fact it is not, because the server will still be responsive to any other clients that connect to the server.  In particular, `select()` will still return right away whenever `serv_sock` or any other client's socket `select()`s as ready-for-read (or ready-for-write) and so the server can handle the other clients just fine while waiting for your hacked/slow client to wake up.

The hacked/slow client might be a problem *for the user*, but there's nothing the server can really do about that (short of forcibly disconnecting the client's TCP connection, or maybe printing out a log message requesting that someone debug the connected client program, I suppose :)).

I agree with EJP, btw -- selecting on ready-for-write should only be done on sockets that you actually want to write some data to.  If you don't actually have any desire to write to the socket ASAP, then it's pointless and counterproductive to instruct `select()` to return as soon as that socket is ready-for-write:  the problem with doing so is that you're likely to spin the CPU a *lot* whenever any socket's outgoing-data-buffer is less-than-full (which in most applications, is most of the time!).  The user-visible symptom of the problem would be that your server program is using up 100% of a CPU core even when it ought to be idle or mostly-idle.

Comment: It occurs to me that the `sleep()` statement might cause the client socket to be unavailable to write to since the buffer gets full during `sleep()`?  I want to simmer on this a while but what you're saying makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, your hypothesis is correct.  (if you want an analogy, think of the TCP connection as a pair of plastic tubes -- one tube for data going in each direction.  In the normal case, the server pushes marbles into its end of the tube, and the client pops marbles out of the other end; but with the client calling `sleep()`, the marbles on its end don't get popped out very often, and eventually the tube fills up so that the server can't push any more marbles in until the next time the client wakes up and takes some out)

Comment: Ok, but if that's the case, I would expect the server-side `send()` to get EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK while the client sleeps, but that's not happening (I edited my test to include more `errno` handling, so there should be explicit warnings any time I hit a socket exception).  For some reason, even with all the changes (including those suggested by EJP), the server is still pausing when the client pauses; it doesn't look like the server is pausing because of a full socket `send()` buffer though.  Any thoughts on what's pausing it in my latest attempt?

Comment: `send()` would return -1 and set errno to `EWOULDBLOCK` if you called `send()` on a (non-blocking) socket whose outgoing buffer is full.  However, your server code never does that; instead it (correctly) only calls `send()` after the socket has selected as ready-for-write, and a socket only selects-as-ready-for-write if it has space in its outgoing-data-buffer.

Comment: I found the problem... the server's loop was blocking on `select()` because I was calling it with a 5-second timeout.  Thank you for your useful input

Comment: I think you misunderstand the behavior of the timeout argument.  The 5-second timeout is a *maximum* time before `select()` returns, not a minimum time.  Without a timeout specified, `select()` will block indefinitely when no sockets have data ready-to-read or buffer-space-ready-to-write-to.

Comment: I don't think I have misunderstood now.  I had the problem with the server pausing when the client called `time.sleep(1)` because the server was waiting in `select()` for more data (but the client was sleeping).  When I call `select(sock_list, [], [], 0.0)` (or even `select(sock_list, [], [], 0.1)`), the server is no longer waiting on the client to send data.  In other words, if I don't want to be blocked by client `time.sleep(SLEEP_FOO)`, my server's `select()` must be lower than `SLEEP_FOO` (preferably much lower - dependent on other requirements).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176902/discussion-between-jeremy-friesner-and-mike-pennington).

Comment: If you don't want select() to ever block for more than 0.1 seconds, then passing in 0.1 as its timeout argument is the right thing to do. However, unless your server actually needs to do something every 0.1 seconds (e.g. update a clock-display or similar) there is no benefit to forcing select() to wake up on a regular basis, since if no sockets are ready to be handled, there is nothing the server can do anyway. In that case, forcing a timeout simply wastes CPU cycles.

Comment: Agreed... that's why I said: *dependent on other requirements* above

Answer (score 2):

TCP sockets are almost always ready for writing, unless their socket send buffer is full.

It is therefore incorrect to always select on writability for a socket. You should only do so after you've encountered a send failure due to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. Otherwise your server will spin mindlessly processing writeable sockets, which will usually be all of them.

Comment: I get what you're saying.  Are you suggesting this is happening specifically because of the client-side `send()` in a select loop?  Also, I'm curious about the case of `send()` to a TCP zero-window if I don't use `select()` on the `send()` side.  Does EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK happen for TCP zero-windows?

Comment: @MikePennington It has nothing to do with the client. The server is spinning mindlessly. If the receive window closes, the send buffer will fill up, and when it fills you will get EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: @EJP when I tested it, the server was in fact *not* spinning the CPU, because the client-socket's outgoing-data-buffer was almost always 100% full and therefore the client-socket was not selecting as ready-for-write very often.  In effect, the server-side bug (always blindly selecting for ready-to-write) was being masked by the client-side 'bug' (sleeping a lot and not reading from the client-side socket in a timely manner).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... the server's loop was blocking on select() because I was calling it with a 5-second timeout.

Adding the explicit solution as an answer...

#### tcp_server.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python -u
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SO_REUSEADDR, SOL_SOCKET
from socket import MSG_DONTWAIT
#from socket import MSG_OOB  <--- for send()
from socket import socket
import socket as socket_module
import select
import errno
import fcntl
import time
import sys
import os

def get_errno_info(e, op='', debugmsg=False):
    """Return verbose information from errno errors, such as errors returned by python socket()"""
    VALID_OP = set(['accept', 'connect', 'send', 'recv', 'read', 'write'])
    assert op.lower() in VALID_OP, "op must be: {0}".format(
        ','.join(sorted(VALID_OP)))

    ## ref: man 3 errno (in linux)... other systems may be man 2 intro
    ##   also see https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html
    try:
        retval_int = int(e.args[0])         # Example: 32
        retval_str = os.strerror(e.args[0]) # Example: 'Broken pipe'
        retval_code = errno.errorcode.get(retval_int, 'MODULEFAIL') # Ex: EPIPE
    except:
        ## I don't expect to get here unless something broke in python errno...
        retval_int  = -1
        retval_str  = '__somethingswrong__'
        retval_code = 'BADFAIL'

    if debugmsg:
        print "DEBUG: Can't {0}() on socket (errno:{1}, code:{2} / {3})".format(
            op, retval_int, retval_code, retval_str)
    return retval_int, retval_str, retval_code


host = ''
port = 6667     # IRC service
DEBUG = True

serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SOCK_STREAM, 1)
serv_sock.bind((host, port))
serv_sock.listen(5)

#fcntl.fcntl(serv_sock, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)  # Make the socket non-blocking
serv_sock.setblocking(False)

sock_list = [serv_sock]

from_client_str = '__DEFAULT__'

to_client_idx = 0
loop_count = 0
need_send_select = False
while True:
    if need_send_select:
        # Only do this after send() EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK...
        send_sock_list = sock_list
    else:
        send_sock_list = []

    #print "---"
    #print "LOOP_COUNT",  loop_count

    recv_ready_list, send_ready_list, exception_ready = select.select(
        sock_list, send_sock_list, [], 0.0)  # Last float is the select() timeout...


    ## Read all sockets which are output-ready... might be client or server...
    for sock_fd in recv_ready_list:

        # accept() if we're reading on the server socket...
        if sock_fd is serv_sock:
            try:
                clientsock, clientaddr = sock_fd.accept()
            except socket_module.error, e:
                errstr, errint, errcode = get_errno_info(e, op='accept',
                    debugmsg=DEBUG)

            assert sock_fd.gettimeout()==0.0, "client socket should be in non-blocking mode"
            sock_list.append(clientsock)

        # read input from the client socket...
        else:
            try:
                from_client_str = sock_fd.recv(1024, MSG_DONTWAIT)
                if from_client_str=='':
                    # Client closed the socket...
                    print "CLIENT CLOSED SOCKET"
                    sock_list.remove(sock_fd)
            except socket_module.error, e:
                errstr, errint, errcode = get_errno_info(e, op='recv',
                    debugmsg=DEBUG)
                if errcode=='EAGAIN' or errcode=='EWOULDBLOCK':
                    # socket unavailable to read()
                    continue
                elif errcode=='ECONNRESET' or errcode=='EPIPE':
                    # Client closed the socket...
                    sock_list.remove(sock_fd)
                else:
                    print "UNHANDLED SOCKET ERROR", errcode, errint, errstr
                    sys.exit(1)


            print "from_client_str: '{0}'".format(from_client_str)

    ## Adding dynamic_list, per input from EJP, below...
    if need_send_select is False:
        dynamic_list = sock_list
    else:
        dynamic_list = send_ready_list
    ## NOTE:  socket code shouldn't walk this list unless a write is pending...
    ##      broadast the same message to all clients...
    for sock_fd in dynamic_list:

        ## Ignore server's listening socket...
        if sock_fd is serv_sock:
            ## Only send() to accept()ed sockets...
            continue

        try:

            to_client_str = "server->client: {0}\n".format(to_client_idx)
            send_retval = sock_fd.send(to_client_str, MSG_DONTWAIT)
            ## send() returns the number of bytes written, on success
            ##     disabling assert check on sent bytes while using MSG_DONTWAIT
            #assert send_retval==len(to_client_str)

            to_client_idx += 1
            need_send_select = False
        except socket_module.error, e:
            errstr, errint, errcode = get_errno_info(e, op='send',
                debugmsg=DEBUG)
            if errcode=='EAGAIN' or errcode=='EWOULDBLOCK':
                need_send_select = True
                continue
            elif errcode=='ECONNRESET' or errcode=='EPIPE':
                # Client closed the socket...
                sock_list.remove(sock_fd)
            else:
                print "FATAL UNHANDLED SOCKET ERROR", errcode, errint, errstr
                sys.exit(1)

    loop_count += 1
```

#### tcp_client.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python -u
    
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from socket import gethostname, socket
import socket as socket_module
import select
import fcntl
import errno
import time
import sys
import os

## NOTE: Using this script to simulate a scheduler
SERVER_HOSTNAME = 'myHostname'
SERVER_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.local'
PORT = 9997

def handle_socket_error_continue(e):
    ## non-blocking socket info from:
    ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745561/667301
    print "HANDLE_SOCKET_ERROR_CONTINUE"
    err = e.args[0]
    if (err==errno.EAGAIN) or (err==errno.EWOULDBLOCK):
        print 'CLIENT DEBUG: No data input from server'
        return True
    else:
        print 'FROM SERVER RECV ERROR: {0}'.format(e)
        sys.exit(1)

c2s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # Client to server socket...
c2s.connect(('.'.join((SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_DOMAIN,)), PORT))
# Set socket non-blocking...
fcntl.fcntl(c2s, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

to_srv_idx = 0
while True:
    socket_list = [c2s]

    # Get the list sockets which can: take input, output, etc...
    recv_ready_list, send_ready_list, exception_ready = select.select(
        socket_list, socket_list, [])

    for sock_fd in recv_ready_list:
        assert sock_fd is c2s, "Strange socket failure here"

        #incoming message from remote server
        try:
            from_srv_str = sock_fd.recv(4096)
        except socket_module.error, e:
            ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745561/667301
            err_continue = handle_socket_error_continue(e)
            if err_continue is True:
                continue
        else:
            if len(from_srv_str)==0:
                print "SERVER CLOSED NORMALLY"
                sys.exit(0)

        ## NOTE: if we get this far, we successfully received from_srv_str.
        ##    Anything caught above, is some kind of fail...
        print "from_srv_str: {0}".format(from_srv_str)

    for sock_fd in send_ready_list:
        #incoming message from remote server
        if sock_fd is c2s:
            #to_srv_str = raw_input('Send to server: ')
            try:
                to_srv_str = 'client->server {0}'.format(to_srv_idx)
                sock_fd.send(to_srv_str)

                               ##
                time.sleep(1)  ## Client blocks the server here... Why????
                               ##

                to_srv_idx += 1
            except socket_module.error, e:
                print "TO SERVER SEND ERROR", e
```