# pygame stop responding while socket receiving data

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

I am trying to make an online tictactoc game with pygame and socket. everything is working well. but there is a small problem that is when the server or client in on receiving mode and waiting to receive data if that takes more than 4 or more sec. then pygame's GUI stops responding. but if data sent then it starts working normally. it happens while receiving data and it took more than 4 or more seconds. please me to solve out

server.py codes

```
import socket
import pygame
import sys


IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5555
Biended_adrs = (IP, PORT)
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(Biended_adrs)
server.listen()
conn, addr = server.accept()
print(f"{addr} connected!")

def Send(row, col):
    data = str((row, col))
    conn.send(data.encode())

def Receive():
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    return data.decode()




pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Server")

GRAY = (100, 111, 111)
LineWidth = 10

def DrawLine():
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (0, 200), (600, 200), LineWidth) # h1
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (0, 400), (600, 400), LineWidth) # h2
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (200, 0), (200, 600), LineWidth) # v1
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (400, 0), (400, 600), LineWidth) # v2

DrawLine()


firstPlayer = conn.recv(1024)
player = firstPlayer.decode()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseX = event.pos[0]
            mouseY = event.pos[1]


            clickedRow = int(mouseY // 200)
            clickedCol = int(mouseX // 200)


            if player == "1":
                try:
                    Send(clickedRow, clickedCol)
                    player = "2"
                    conn.send(player.encode())
                except Exception:
                    pass

            else:
                pass
        if player == "2":
            try:
                Clientdata = Receive()
                print(Clientdata, "Client Send!")
                player = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                print(player)
                receive = False
            except Exception:
                pass

        else:
            pass


        pygame.display.update()
```

client.py codes

```
import socket
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")


HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5555

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))

draw = DrawLine()

def Send(row, col):
    data = str((row, col))
    client.send(data.encode())

def Receive():
    data = client.recv(1024)
    return data.decode()

GRAY = (100, 111, 111)
LineWidth = 10

def DrawLine():
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (0, 200), (600, 200), LineWidth) # h1
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (0, 400), (600, 400), LineWidth) # h2
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (200, 0), (200, 600), LineWidth) # v1
    pygame.draw.line(display, GRAY, (400, 0), (400, 600), LineWidth) # v2


firstPlayer = "1"
client.send(firstPlayer.encode())
player = "1"

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        If event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseX = event.pos[0]
            mouseY = event.pos[1]
            clickedRow = int(mouseY // 200)
            clickedCol = int(mouseX // 200)

            if player == "2":
                try:
                    Send(clickedRow, clickedCol)
                    player = "1"
                    client.send(player.encode())
                except Exception:
                    pass


        if player == "1":
            try:
                data = Receive()
                print(data, "Server Send!")
                player = client.recv(1024).decode()
                print(player)
            except Exception:
                pass
        else:
            pass


        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

> socket.recv(bufsize[, flags]) Receive data from the socket. The return
> value is a bytes object representing the data received. The maximum
> amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize. See the
> Unix manual page recv(2) for the meaning of the optional argument
> flags; it defaults to zero.

It points you to flags you can use, in the underlying OS implementation. I don't know the portable way to do this, but the functionality you want is to pass `MSG_DONTWAIT`. That way, if a message has not arrived yet, you get to learn about it. That means your program can continue to animate and try again later. You'll need to return `None` in the meantime, and adjust your code to detect that and retry again until the message has arrived.

There is also: `socket.SOCK_NONBLOCK` in Python. this might be the flag to pass:

```
conn.recv(1024, flags = socket.SOCK_NONBLOCK)
```

but don't forget to check the returned value before trying to decode it.

Comment: I am still confused. but I have tried the flag after watching your answer but it says "AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'SOCK_NONBLOCK' " will you please provide me some example

Comment: Look at the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745409/what-does-pythons-socket-recv-return-for-non-blocking-sockets-if-no-data-is-r/16745561#16745561